# Couldn't find HttpResponse or HttpServletResponse in Spring 4

Tags: download, httpresponse, spring-4

Just I am working on web project, In that i need to download a sql file while clicking the link. I tried to find the **HttpResponse** or **HttpServletResponse** in controller. Could any one help me to resolve this issue,

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/downloadFile.htm", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public void toDownloadFile(@RequestParam("fileName") String fileName,
            HttpServletResponse response) {
        File file = new File(fileName);
        if (file != null) {
            try {

                response.setContentType("application/sql");
                // response.setContentLength((new
                // Long(file.getLength()).intValue()));
                response.setHeader("content-Disposition",
                        "attachment; filename=" + fileName);
                FileCopyUtils.copy(fileName, response.getOutputStream());
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                LOGGER.error("Exception in toDownloadFile :" + ex);
            }
        }
    }
```

But in Spring 3 its available, I hope they removed or renamed the HttpServletResponse in Spring 4. Because **HttpServeltRequest** has been moved to org.springframework.web.context.request.**WebRequest**. Any one looked into this? Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HttpServeltRequest and HttpServletResponse are javax interfaces not spring.

Are your project dependencies set up correctly?

```
javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse
```

[org.springframework.web.context.request.WebRequest](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.4.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/context/request/WebRequest.html) has been around for a while and is documented as...

> Generic interface for a web request. Mainly intended for generic web request interceptors, giving them access to general request metadata, not for actual handling of the request.